# How to delete or remove an array value randomly in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I delete an value from an array in jQuery?

```
var prodCode = ["001","002","003","004","005","006","007","008"];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

hopefully i got your question right: you want to delete a single element of an array

```
var index = $.inArray(value, array);
if (index >= 0) {
   array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

otherwise

```
$.each(arrayWithValuesToRemove, function (index, element) {
   var index = $.inArray(element, array);
   if (index < 0) {
      return;
   }
   array.splice(index, 1);
});
```

if you just want a random removal

```
var desiredIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
array.splice(desiredIndex, 1);
```

if you want to keep the index, but not it's value (combine with any of the upper examples):

```
delete array[index];
```

if you want to write your own compare-method (eg. object as value):

```
var compareFunction = function (element) {
    // TODO your compare stuff
};
var getIndexFunction = function (array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var element = array[i];
        if (compareMethod(element)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
var index = getIndexFunction(myArray);
if (index >= 0) {
    myArray.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: if i want to delete a particular index value means, how to do?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I get your question correctly, but if you want to remove a random element in the middle of the array, you can

```
array.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length), 1);
```

Comment: if i want to delete a particular index value means, how to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
var prodCode = ["001","002","003","004","005","006","007","008"];
var randomElementIndex = Math.floor( Math.random() * prodCode.length );
var removedElement = prodCode.splice(randomElementIndex, 1);
console.log(prodCode); //doesn't have removedElement with the index randomElementIndex anymore
```

Removes a **random** element from the array.

Comment: if i want to delete a particular index value means, how to do?

Comment: instead of generating the index randomly, you can just provide it to the splice method of the array literal

Comment: If you want to get the index of an element from its value, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: `.indexOf` is not supported by every browser. use `$.inArray()` instead (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray)

Comment: hence the link to MDN that you obviously didn't check out =) (gives a workaround for non-supporting browsers)

Comment: if the OP is already using jQuery, why not use it for this trivial task? why reinvent the wheel and add another tiny script to your library ...?!

Comment: because it is %20 faster. please refer to your profiler. (not to mention the fact that there is no guarantee that jQuery is used for something else on the project and the inclusion of the library may become obsolete) (reinventing the wheel works really well provided that you can build a really round one)

Comment: ...and please do not take my comments as defensive or even offensive. You may be 100% right; it totally depends on the situation. I just wanted to prove my point^^

Comment: just keep the term `preoptimization` in mind ... the ui is the very last place for optimizations - first comes db/bl... just my point of view :) (paper in our mother tongue: http://www.wicket-praxis.de/blog/2009/11/16/pre-optimization-erkennen-und-vermeiden/)